# Scale image to fit to A4 page - Migradoc

Tags: c#, migradoc

I am really struggling to get this right, any help would be appreciated.

I have a series of images that I want to build in to a PDF using MigraDoc (1 image = 1 page) 
Each image must be displayed on a separate page but may not extend over the page it must fit on to the page perfectly.

So, how do I scale an image (of any size) to fit to a page using MigraDoc?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You call `AddImage()` to add the image - and in return you get an Image object that allows you to set width and/or height of the image.

What you have to do: check the dimensions of the image, calculate which is the limiting factor (width or height), then set this limiting factor on the Image object and also set `LockAspectRatio`.

Or set both `Width` and `Height` and leave `LockAspectRatio` off.

For DIN A4, you may allow e.g. 19 cm x 27.7 cm as maximum image size.
For an image with 1000x1000 pixel you would set the width to 19 cm (assuming `LockAspectRatio` is on). Height will then also be 19 cm automatically.
For an image with 1000x2000 pixel you would set the height to 27.7 cm. Width will then be 50% of the height.